# Enable overriding of images outside Quarkus application

Tags: quarkus

we are porting to quearkus from weblogic. in weblogic war there is option to define "virtual web directoty" which enables overriding web resource in war. i.e. if user ask for http://host:port/some/path/to/page.html  if the page exists in the virtual dir it will be taken from this dir' and if not it will be takem from the war.

I am looking for same logic in quarkus i.e define some folder that if a file exists there it will be served from the folder and if not it will be served from app jar module.

I added undertow-handlers.conf with path-prefix('/some/path/to') -> resource(location='/some/path/to',allow-listing=true) but this only serve file from the disk. But if the file is not there it will not serve anything even if it exists as resource in the jar)

Comment: What exact configuration are youy looking to override?

Comment: i am not looking to override configuration. i am looking for a way to achive the functionality described. above (same as  Virtual Directory settings in web logic https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/weblogic_xml.html#1039396

Comment: Have you read https://quarkus.io/guides/http-reference#serving-static-resources ?

Comment: sure, and like I wrote, I managed to server the file using the undertow handler. What i do not know how to do is how to use this handler only if the files exists in the static directory and if it is not there server the file from the resources directory in the jar